# Where is Commander Bailey's assistant?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the mission Aria: Eclipse it says to speak to Commander Bailey's assistant at the Presidium Commons C-Sec station, but that's where Bailey was and I can't see his assistant anywhere. I assume I'm just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Bailey's in his office in the Embassy area, not the commons. The commons is the open-air area where Liara is sitting outside a cafe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Bailey himself is on the Citadel embassy floor, Bailey's assistant is on a different floor of the Citadel, the Presidium Commons. He's at the C-Sec outpost there, marked with (5) on the following map:

[image]

The assistant is the Turian sitting at the desk:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When you enter the Presidium, turn right, go forward until you find the first wall (a little past the Vorcha talking to the woman about a billboard they're watching), and continue bordering the wall it.
You'll go a little "outside", down some steps, and the C-Sec office will be on your right.

Commander Bailey's assistant will be sitting at his desk.

Comment: As an aside, make sure to speak to Officer Bailey first, otherwise his assistant won't be interactable.

Answer (score 4):

Bailey is in the *Citadel Embassy* C-Sec station. If you go to the Presidium Commons, which is a different floor, there should be a point labeled as a C-Sec station on the map. The assistant should be near that point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk to Bailey first. After talking the matter over with him...he tells you to go talk to his assistant who is in the Presidium Commons, labeled as 5 on the minimap in that area. The mission objectives for this set of quests was a little cryptic and not all that helpful.